# Sql anywhere connection

Tags: sqlanywhere

I want to ask if anyone know a way or a free driver that I can connect to sql anywhere 10 .db file.

I mean a driver that is as a free license because I just have to make my application add few rows in another application database and since I'm not going to use this other database for anything else I need some kind of driver or some workaround to be able to write in sql anywhere db without buing license.

I'm not trying to break anyone autor rights or anything just most databases have free driver that you can use just for simple tasks that is why I'm asking if I'm missing something. 
Thanks for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can register for the developer edition download, that comes with the driver, and its free :).

http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1016644

also you should be aware that if you are connecting to an authenticated database you need to authenticate within 30 seconds

http://dcx.sybase.com/1001/en/dbdaen10/da-running-s-3420607.html

"every connection has a thirty second grace period before the restrictions apply"

Comment: This does not work for me since i want to use the connection at the client computer and this developer license is only for the developer machine

Comment: In that case would the client tools (http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1087327) be of any use to you?  They include the ODBC drivers.